# pouchdb find $or operator unknown

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to use pouchdb.find but keep on getting an unknown operator error.

```
{"message":"unknown operator \"$or\" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type or $all"}
```

I'm a bit lost becuase all of the documentation I read says that $or is available.

package.json:

```
"pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
"pouchdb-find": "^6.3.4",
```

JavaScript:

```
db.find({
     selector: { 
         type: 'question',
         tags: { $or: [ '202', '206' ] } 
     },
     use_index: 'tagSearch',
     include_docs: true
 }).then()...
```

I have a feeling that I am missing something basic. I'm looking to retrieve all documents that have one or the other tag listed in the selector. Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works with `selector: { $or: [{ tags: '202' }, { tags: '206' }] }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to restructure that.

I'm doing an AND in my find and have it setup like this -

```
      db.find({
        selector: {
          $and: [
            { type: { $exists: true } },
            { type: { $eq: "sessions" } },
            { start_date: { $gt: true } },
            { start_date: { $eq: "2018-10-21" } }
          ]
        }
```

You many need something like (didn't test it, not sure that's the correct syntax.

```
        db.find({
          selector: {
            type: 'question',
            $or: [                 
                {tags: '202'},                                      
                {tags: '206'},                                      
            ]
          }
        })
```

Alternately you could try using an IN

```
        selector: {
            tags: {
                $in: [ "202", "206" ]
            }
        }
```

Home some of that helps.